# How to store multiple key value, where value is an array of elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a quick way to crate a key values pair in JavaScript, where I have a key it's an ID, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... 100 and the values are an array composed by a reference, name and quantity.

Is this an appropriate syntax?

> ```
> var petfoodRefData = {
>     "1": [
>             {"ref":5222, "description":"purina", "qtt":500},
>             {"ref":5322, "description":"hills", "qtt":500},
>             {"ref":6222, "description":"hills junior", "qtt":500}
>         ],
>     "2": {"ref":8022, "description":"fatcat", "qtt":60}
> }
> ```

Is there an easier better way to do this? I basically want to for every ID = 1 give me all pet food references, and add them to the document.

Comment: For arrays (the ones that are just a collection of values, and not key-value pairs), you would use square brackets.

Comment: If you have every number between 1 and 100 as an ID it would be a better approach to use an array for `petfoodRedData`. I.e. it would be more readable, internally javascript handles arrays as objects.

Comment: the issue is that the ID had to searchable, because i can have holes in the ID.

Comment: Okay, so I think your approach is the best way to achive this; just use square brackets instead of the `{}` for the array definition and you are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close:

```
var petfoodRefData = {
    "1": [
        {"ref":5222, "description":"purina", "qtt":500},
        {"ref":5322, "description":"hills", "qtt":500},
        {"ref":6222, "description":"hills junior", "qtt":500}
    ],
    "2": [{ "ref":8022, "description":"fatcat", "qtt":60} ]
};
```

Use `[]` for arrays.